# I have a mess in my head regarding redirect 301,mails and moving to a new website

Tags: wordpress, email, redirect, dns

I'm new to the web world and i have a great mess in my head.
i got a project to build a website for a company and i did.
now this website was built with some cms and i built it with Wordpress.
So now i have to take care that some of the SEO meta tags will not ruin when moving to the new website, i used YOAST SEO plugin to do so.
Now my boss is keeping on asking about redirect 301 which i don't understand why do i need to use it?
if we dont transfer any campaigns and only moving to a new website why do i need it?

another problem is the mails on the domain.
the company has like 5 mails on the domain adress and the domain is sitting on the old company they used to work with,which are not cooperative.
how do i transfer the mails from their servers to a new one?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The 301 redirects are for the newly created Url's.

Because every site has their own way or wwriting url's you need to make sure that you carry across the links to the old urls to the new url structure of the wordpress site.

Example
sitename.com/about_us.html is now sitename.com/about-us/ you will then need to redirect the old about_us url to the new one.

This ensures that any old indexed or shared pages don't server a page not found error.

Very important and can be done using the HTACCESS file or a redirect plugin.

Comment: ps. The mails are a totally different issue.

Comment: So how can i know what i need to redirect?

Comment: What you need to do is if you have a full copy of the old website, get all the url's and then redirect them to the new url's. Alternatively, if you do not have it then go ahead and check your google analytics and see what pages are serving 404 errors. ps. remember to mark this as answered if you are happy with the answer.

Comment: If i only want to save the SEO so i don't need to redirect right?

Comment: Recommended to redirect